# Where near the Dead Sea can you most likely get to see a Hyrax?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, israel, dead-sea

I am planning to visit the Dead Sea, and from what I have gathered through online research, Ein Gedi is the place where I can find high end hotels.

I am actually hoping to get a close look at Hyrax during my visit as I am an animal lover? Is there any such place nearby Ein Gedi where you are guaranteed to come across a Hyrax or two, or you would just have to be lucky to see one?

Here's a Rock Hyrax picture...

[image]

**EDIT:**

Finally managed to get a close look. Thanks for all the help guys. Here's the pic!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There is indeed such a place next to Ein Gedi, called [Nahal David (David Creek)](https://goo.gl/maps/dGhhjAbPnrQ2). Though nothing is guaranteed with wild animals.

#### Full Answer

> I am actually hoping to get a close look at Hyrax

A *close* look? How close? Your best bet is to look for a zoo that holds them in a small cage. Other than that, these are wild animals, and it won't be easy to catch a close look at one. I heard that there are some in the [Ramat Gan Safari](http://www.safari.co.il/index.php?tlng=eng), though I could not confirm that from that website - you want might to call or email and ask.

That said, the Rock Hyrax is a common animal in Israel, and I've seen families many times, especially in the north of the country. If you go hiking in the Galilee or Carmel region you are likely to find some. However, if I was actively looking for them, I'd go to a colony whose location is well known. Examples I know of:

- [Nahal David (David Creek)](https://goo.gl/maps/dGhhjAbPnrQ2) - that's right next to Ein Gedi. I can really recommend this - I've personally seen Hyraxes and Ibexes there, pretty close by. So your choice - Ein Gedi - is actually great in that regard!
- [Rosh Hanikra](http://www.akko.org.il/en/Rosh-Hanikra-Tourist-Site-) - there's a colony on the rocks near the parking lot, and more on actual rock formations above. You can also see them from above when you approach the entrance to the site (after the parking lot).
- [Kibbutz Shamir](https://goo.gl/maps/UeC7YjVwTQw) - there's been a colony there for ages, from what I understand.

#### Final Tips

1. Rock Hyraxes are mostly active in the mornings, I've read that sunrise to 9 am are the best times to spot them.
2. The Ein Gedi area is absolutely breathtaking, but it's not a particularly good hub for touring the rest of the country - Tel Aviv or Jerusalem are better for that. Though admittedly it's overall a tiny country.

Comment: Finally managed to get a look after all these years. Thanks for the tips! Added the pic in the edit.

Answer (score 12):

Speaking strictly statistically, judging by the official [range of the creature](http://maps.iucnredlist.org/map.html?id=41766), it actually runs in two bands from the north of the Dead Sea, down the west a bit, and down the east.  Notably, not SW (you may have to zoom into the map).

Animals are of course, wild and hard to predict - the bane of anyone looking for something in a wildlife reserve.  However, often locals might point to where a family of the animal has been recently, so do ask around.  For example, in Cape Town, South Africa, there's a known group of dassies (Afrikaans for 'hyrax') that live at the top of the cable car on Table Mountain (go figure!).

Otherwise it often comes down to luck, so good luck!

EDIT: additional Ein Gedi notes:

- [Apparently it's the natural food of the local wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_hyrax), so you could follow those...?
- They've been spotted in the [Ein Gedi Nature Reserve](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g293979-d318964-i59279371-Ein_Gedi_Nature_Reserve-Dead_Sea_Region.html)
- [Another one in the Nature reserve](http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g293979-d318964-i136974202-Ein_Gedi_Nature_Reserve-Dead_Sea_Region.html)

Comment: I meant I was hoping to find a place within a distance of few hours travel from Ein Gedi where I can be sure to run into a Hyrax. Looks like Ein Gedi Nature Reserve offers a high probability.

Comment: Yeah that's why I added the bit at the end, agree that your best bet seems like the reserve.  Let us know if you see them!!

Comment: @Gaurav Israel isn't very big: Google maps suggests that the entire country is within about three hours' drive of Ein Gedi.

Comment: Like Ephraim Kishon once said: "Come to Israel, just for a day, and I'll show around the country. But what shall we do in the afternoon?"

Comment: @MarkMayo Saw it finally. Added the pic in the edit. Thanks!